# Invalid CORS on Angular 12 with Java Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot, cors

I have an angular application that uses a proxy to access the java spring boot backend and other services:

proxy.conf.js:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
        "/my/api/context/**"
    ],
    target: "http://localhost:9000/",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    secure: false,
    logLevel: "debug",
    changeOrigin: true,
  },
  ...
}]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

MyController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my/api/controller/path")
public class MyController {
    ...
    @PostMapping("/endpoint/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> endpoint(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm also using zookeeper for some environment configurations.

The issue is that for GET requests, my angular application works fine but for any other verb, I get a `403 Forbidden` error and a `Invalid CORS request` message from spring boot. What's weird is that when I copy the request with all the headers and submit via Postman, I get a `200` response with no problems.

There are many questions regarding this problem on the web but all seem to point to a backend issue. In this case the backend seem to be well configured (the Postman request is successful).

I'm sure I'm missing something trivial but just can't put my finger on it. Anyone has any idea what could be going wrong here? Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. If you need anything else, just let me know and I'll see if I can share.

**EDIT #1:**

my.service.ts:

```
myPost(id: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit strange because if you use the proxy, there shouldn't be any CORS at all. Can you show the Angular code you use to call your API? (eg. the `HttpClient`-related stuf?) This also looks like a different configuration than the proxy.json configuration from Angular CLI.

Comment: @g00glen00b I have edited the question to show the angular function that calls the api; Regarding the proxy: It is a little different but it has worked so far for many other services but if you find anything specially weird let me know and I'll test.

Comment: What does `this.endpoint` refer to?

Comment: @g00glen00b the path that matches the proxy. "/my/api/context/" in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Just add

`@CrossOrigin`

On your controller class and it should solve the issue.

Comment: I did and it didn't help.

Comment: OP uses proxy for a reason, e.g., so he does not have to compromise security and set localhost for allowed origins for a reason. or ALL origins as you suggested without even implying to do this only for development

Answer (score -1):

I just had to set:

```
changeOrigin: false,
```

And it worked.

Comment: That produces ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID